# Formula for succesively computing and assigning score value to quiz questions in my program

Tags: combinatorics, summation, algorithms

Hello please forgive my question is not suited for this place, I am not very good at math and I need help.

I have a computer program which is a quiz. As per my plan, each individual quiz question would have a "value" based on the correct/incorrect attempts.
After the quiz ends the user gets his simple score (+2 for correct, -0.66 for incorrect and 0 for no attempt) and a comparison based score based on how he performed compared to other students on the platform which would computed using the individual question "value".

I am having a hard time coming up with a formula that assign/update the questions value every time the quiz question is successively attempted by hundreds of users. (each question would have a default score at the beginning).

I seems apparent that a high success question would have a low score, and a low success question would have a high score.

Comment: This is fairly vague.  You could, for instance, just assign a "score" to each question equal to the fraction of prior test takers who got it wrong.  Thus you get no points if everybody before you got it right and you get one point if everybody before you got it wrong.  You can rescale that if you like.  If that doesn't do want you want, edit your post to explain exactly why it falls short.  The clearer you are about the metric you want, the easier it will be to design one.

Comment: thank you, this is exactly how I plan to assign and compute scores.